# How do I deal rootViews when I want to launch from a push notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

My app has an embedded navigation controller. I want to launch a particular viewController that is not the initial view or rootViewController.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
NSDictionary *dictionary = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];

if (dictionary != nil)
{
    UIViewController *rootController = (UIViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
UIViewController *notificationController = [rootController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NotificationsViewController"];
[rootController presentViewController:notificationController animated:NO completion:^{

}];
 }
}
```

I know I have to input the code in here but am not sure how exactly I can code it. Can someone help? I get the error code:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <NotificationsViewController: 0x176883a0> on <SWRevealViewController: 0x17683750> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

SWRevealViewController is my library for my sidebar view. My guess is that my "root" isn't what I think it is.

If I want to set viewControllerX as my root view, how can I accomplish this?

Comment: one thing needs to ask. how does your application work when its launched without options ??? from what I see, there is no code to function when launchOptions is nil.  

then next thing is you need to create a UIWindow instance first before calling self.window.rootViewController.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize your rootViewController first.

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];    
YourViewControllerX * viewControllerX = [[YourViewControllerX alloc] init];
self.window.rootViewController = viewControllerX;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: (NSDictionary *)launchOptions{
    [self.window addSubview:self.window.rootViewController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
    if (dictionary != nil){
        ...
    }
}
```